# How can I calculate the duration of my text file in awk

Tags: awk

I have a big text file similar to this demo:

```
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:11:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AA  Stock: AALB.AA
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:11:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AA Stock: ABN.AA
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:12:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AA Stock: AD.AA
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:12:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AS Stock: AGN.AS
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:12:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AS Stock: AKZA.AS
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:13:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AS Stock: ASML.AS
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:13:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AS Stock: ATC.AS
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:14:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AS Stock: BOKA.AS
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:14:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AS Stock: DSM.AS
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:14:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AS Stock: GLPG.AS
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:15:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AS Stock: GTO.AS
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:15:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AS Stock: HEIA.AS
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:15:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AS Stock: INGA.AS
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:15:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AS Stock: KPN.AS
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:16:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AS Stock: MT.AS
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:16:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AS Stock: NN.AS
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:16:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AS Stock: PHIA.AS
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:16:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AS Stock: RAND.AS
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:17:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AS Stock: RDSA.AS
  --> [Calc: 2020-06-02 12:17:25] Doing TrendFollowing now for TradeDate [pendingTradDate]: 2016-11-15 and country: AS Stock: REN.AS
```

Now I would like to calculate for each country (here in the demo only on f.e. SS) the Calc Durations:

I have done this with awk:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ":"
    OFS = ","
}

{
    idx = substr($6, 1, 3)
    a[idx]++
    dt[idx] = $2 ":" $3 ":" substr($4, 1, 2)
    az[idx] = dt2secs(dt[idx])
    Prod[az[idx]]++
    min[az[idx]] = Prod[az[idx]] == 1 || min[az[idx]] > az[idx] ? az[idx] : min[az[idx]]
    max[az[idx]] = max[az[idx]] < az[idx] ? az[idx] : max[az[idx]]
}

END {
    for (i in a) {
        print i, a[i] - 1, dt[idx], az[idx], secs2dt(max[az[idx]]), secs2dt(min[az[idx]]), secs2hms(max[az[idx]] - min[az[idx]])
    }
}


function dt2secs(dt)
{
    return mktime(gensub(/[-:]/, " ", "g", dt))
}

function secs2dt(s)
{
    return strftime("Time = %m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", s)
}

function secs2hms(s)
{
    return sprintf("%d:%02d:%02d hrs", s / (60 * 60), (s / 60) % 60, s % 60)
}
```

Can anyone here help me an tell me why my output of the awk file is wrong? [The min and max values are all the same for each country.]

```
     AA,2, 2020-06-02 12:17:25, 2020-06-02 12:17:25,1591093045,Time = 06/02/2020 12:17:25,Time = 06/02/2020 12:12:25,0:05:00 hrs
     AS,16, 2020-06-02 12:17:25, 2020-06-02 12:17:25,1591093045,Time = 06/02/2020 12:17:25,Time = 06/02/2020 12:12:25,0:05:00 hrs
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the advices:
I could do a step to the solution:

```
     BEGIN { FS=":"; OFS="," ;}
     function dt2secs(dt) { return mktime(gensub(/[-:]/," ","g",dt)) }
     function secs2hms(s) { return sprintf("%d:%02d:%02d hrs",s/(60*60),(s/60)%60,s%60) }
     function secs2dt(s) { return strftime("Time = %m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", s);}
     {idx=substr($6,1,3); a[idx]++; dt[idx]=$2":"$3":"substr($4,1,2); az[idx]=dt2secs(dt[idx]);
     Prod[idx]++;
     min[idx]=Prod[idx]==1||min[idx]>az[idx]?az[idx]:min[idx];
     max[idx]=max[idx]<az[idx]?az[idx]:max[idx];
     }
     END {for (i in a) {print i,a[i]-1,dt[idx],az[idx],secs2dt(max[idx]),secs2dt(min[idx]),secs2hms(max[idx]-min[idx]) }}
```

But I can not find the bug why the min and max values are the same for all countries. Can one open my eyes, please?

EDIT: I found my mistake: in the last line there must be i instead of idx.

```
     END {for (i in a) {print i,a[i]-1,dt[idx],az[i],secs2dt(max[i]),secs2dt(min[i]),secs2hms(max[i]-min[i]) }}
```

Comment: Adding readability of the code goes a long way (beautified by `gawk -o-`)

Comment: so, the output is correctly formatted but you don't like what time gets printed. Why don't you? Can you explain _how_ the output is wrong?

Comment: Can you exaplin the code? `min[az[idx]]` Why do you _index_ minimum values with seconds?

Comment: @KamilCuk yes I want now the min and max of the times per country. But I always get the min and max for all the countries the same

Comment: `per country.` so shouldn't you index with the country?

Comment: @KamilCuk yes I found it also at the same time tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 BEGIN {
     FS = ":"
     OFS = ","
 }

 {
     idx = substr($6, 1, 3)
     a[idx]++
     dt[idx] = $2 ":" $3 ":" substr($4, 1, 2)
     idx = dt2secs(dt[idx])
     Prod[idx]++
     min[idx] = Prod[idx] == 1 || min[idx] > idx ? idx : min[idx]
     max[idx] = max[idx] < idx ? idx : max[idx]
 }

 END {
     for (i in a) {
     print i, a[i] - 1, dt[i],  secs2dt(max[i]), secs2dt(min[i]), secs2hms(max[i] - min[i])
     }
 }
 function dt2secs(dt)
 {
     return mktime(gensub(/[-:]/, " ", "g", dt))
 }

 function secs2dt(s)
 {
     return strftime("Time = %m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", s)
 }

 function secs2hms(s)
 {
     return sprintf("%d:%02d:%02d hrs", s / (60 * 60), (s / 60) % 60, s % 60)
 }
```

the output is correct now:

```
     AA,2, 2020-06-02 12:17:25,1591092745,Time = 06/02/2020 12:12:25,Time = 06/02/2020 12:11:25,0:01:00 hrs
     AS,16, 2020-06-02 12:17:25,1591093045,Time = 06/02/2020 12:17:25,Time = 06/02/2020 12:12:25,0:05:00 hrs
```

Comment: @EdMorton I did the beautifieing. But in my Questions this was done by Inian (See 1 commend)